# VMWare Workstation guests cannot access the network with ethernet switch inline

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

Solved this, see my comment following this main post.

==================

I have a pair of Windows 7 hosts running VMWare Workstation 10 and Ubuntu guests. I recently introduced a Netgear ethernet switch to my network, so the hosts are connected to the router via the upstream switch. (Previously one machine was directly connected on the wire, second machine was using wireless connect).

Prior to using the switch, the guests on my wired host were using bridged mode, and everything was fine. After introducing the switch, the guests in bridged mode no longer connect to the network. I can connect using NAT, but the goal is to allow all guests to see other guests in the same IP range.

Strangely, if I run Oracle Virtual Box, those guests are able to connect using Bridged mode, and obtain IP addresses via DHCP from my router, and are visible on my routers map, etc.

For some reason, guests in VMWare Workstation in bridged mode, are not able to reach across this switch and talk to the router. Again, the goal is for all guests to see one another on the main network, across physical hosts.

I have tried this on 2 different switches, and I have also tried disabling the firewall on the host, but still no connection in bridged mode for the guests.

Comment: Ahhh.....what about windows firewall actions?

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned at the bottom I tried disabling Windows firewall. I dug around on the VMWare forums, and one guy mentioned that his anti-virus software interfered with his VMWare guests. So I disabled the entire AV software (Avast) and it started working. Odd however, that this worked fine with this same AV software without the switch. I can only surmise the switch introduces different packets that the AV software interprets incorrectly and prevents the connections.